# @Valid annotation works with @RequestBody but not with RequestEntity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jsr349

Spring MVC's `@Valid` annotation works as expected with `@RequestBody` arg but it's not working with `RequestEntity` arg. Is there anyway to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

`@Valid` is not from Spring MVC, `@Valid` relies under package `javax.validation;` Maybe you meant `@Validated`. Nevertheless `@RequestBody` and `RequestEntity` have to be taken differently in terms of validation.

`@RequestBody` is used in a Spring MVC Controller to annotate the payload of a request, but has nothing to do with validation of this incoming payload object.

`RequestEntity` is used to wrap the actual payload in preparation for a new request. No validation is applied when you create a new RequestEntity.

Comment: Is it not correct to accept the request in a spring mvc controller as RequestEntity instead of @RequestBody?

Comment: Sure, It is allowed.

Comment: Then how do I use jsr303 to validate the RequestEntity body? @Valid didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Valid` annotation worked with `@RequestBody` because the `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` (which does the work of resolving this handler argument) looks for the presence of `@Valid` and, if it is found, applies all matching validators it finds in the `WebDataBinder`.

On the other hand, `ResponseEntity` arguments are resolved by `HttpEntityMethodProcessor`, which does not perform validation even if the argument is annotated with `@Valid`.

You can, of course, perform validation manually in the handler method by invoking a validator of your choosing. It’s certainly possible, although you might want to consider a different approach.

Comment: Thanks. So, it's a new feature request.